# Did Bartenura really mention this minhag?

Tags: minhag, grapes-wine, bartenura

There is a quote making the social media rounds which claims the Bartenura mentions a minhag he witnessed on his way to Jerusalem where people would drink wine before going to shul on Friday night.

From [Otzar Yad Chaim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36141&pgnum=89):

[image]

The claim is that Bartenura wrote this in his seffer Darkei Tzion.

Is this true?

[A related question.](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109715/does-the-yerushalmi-mention-drinking-wine-on-friday-after-bathing)

Comment: Is that from taamei minhagim

Comment: See edit, Sam. Menachem edited this into my other related question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> עוד מנהג ליהודים מארץ ישמעאל
>   בערב שבת הולכים כלם לבית המרחץ
>   ובשובם מביאות נשותיהם לפניהם יין ומרבים בשתיה ואחר מביאות התבשיל שהכינו לסעודת הערב אוכלים מבעוד יום עד שתחשך
>   ואחר באים כולם לבית הכנסת במלבושיהם נקיים ומגוהצים ומתחילים בשירות ותשבחות ומאריכים בתפילת ערבית עד שתי שעות בלילה ובאים לבתיהם ומקדשין אוכלים כזית לחם ומברכים ברכת המזון ואין מתפללים תפילת המנחה של ערב שבת בצבור בכל גלילות ההם זולתי בירושלים לבדה 
>   נתבטל המנהג ההיא שבטלו אותו האשכנזים
>
> Another custom of the Jews of Muslim lands: on Friday they all go the bathhouse and upon their return their wives bring before them wine and they drink a lot and then they bring the cooked food which they prepared for the evening meal and they eat it whilst still daytime until it darkens, and after that they all come to the synagogue in their clean and pressed clothes and they begin songs and praises and extend the Arvit prayer until two hours in the night, and they come to their houses and say Kiddush and eat an olive's bulk of bread and bless the Blessings of Bread, and they do not pray the Mincha prayer communally on Friday in all those lands except only in Jerusalem where that custom had been abolished by the Ashkenazim.

-- from Rav Ovadia Bartenura's [*Darkei Tzion*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36661&st=&pgnum=11) describing his travels in the land of Israel in the late 15th Century

Comment: And in the paragraphs before that he describes the Shabbat drinking schedule.