# Does the Yerushalmi mention drinking wine on Friday after bathing

Tags: grapes-wine, talmud-yerushalmi, leil-shabbat

Related to [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/109691/did-bartenura-really-mention-this-minhag) question. The [Otzar Yad Chaim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=36141&pgnum=89) in the picture below quotes the Bartenura who mentions a minhag to drink until tipsy before going to shul Friday night.

The seffer then says the Yerushalmi in Brachos mentions drinking wine after the bathhouse on Friday.

Where is this Yerushalmi?

[image: Otzar Yad Chaim 874]

Comment: Maybe he's thinking of 6:5 חמר בתר בילני

Comment: @Double I think you're right. All the rishonim (Raavad Rosh) in Tur 174:4 are quoting Rava who says the mishna is only talking about erev shabbos. So put that together with this Yerushalmi and that's the source. Consider posting as an answer so I can upvote and accept. Thanks